# react-native-fbsdk: "ld: library not found for -l-lRNSDKCoreKit"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

After reading several StackOverflow posts about similar issues, I'm still stuck with this error on iOS `ld: library not found for -l-lRNSDKCoreKit`. Below are steps that I have confirmed:

1. `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` is present with all files
2. All 4 Framework files have been added to XCode as per FBSDK documentation
3. `Framework Search Paths` and `Link Binary With libraries` also looks good.
4. I do not have a `.xcworkspace` file so I am using the `.xcodeproj` file

**Very Interesting Fact**

Running `react-native unlink react-native-fbsdk` and linking manually on Android fixes the problem and FB login works just fine.

**Environment**

XCode: 8.3.3 (latest)
FBSDK: 4.26.0 (latest)
react-native-fbsdk: 0.6.1 (latest)
react-native: 0.46.4
react: 16.0.0-alpha.12

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was due to [an issue with version 0.6.1 of react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10032). The link step failed, and appears to have left the iOS project in a weird state. The breaking change is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/commit/f27d02831c35a14790b40cc5c1c2381d480b028f#commitcomment-22823798). Switching to version 0.6.0 fixed this for me:

```
> react-native unlink react-native-fbsdk
> react-native uninstall react-native-fbsdk
> react-native install react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've solved this problem by updating XCode version 8.2.1 to 9.0.HH